# Is it good to use echo or go's templates to show complex data in frontend?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, go, templates, view

Go's [template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) syntax doesn't have the ability to manipulate data in the frontend. For example, sending a map from the server, to show all the data in the map, in a html file, there isn't a method to check if an array(in the map)'s index is odd or even. Also, there is no way to perform math calculations or string operations in the html template.

All the data should be prepared in the server side then sent to frontend. This OK for showing but difficult in a loop.

A frontend framework such as Vue or React is powerful enough to do this, but then data should be posted as JSON.  But using just Go or [Echo](https://echo.labstack.com/guide/templates) you can't do a complex view operation. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually depends. You would use client-side/front-end SPA (Single Page Applications) frameworks when you need interactivity on front-end code. Such requirements are defined by UX needs of the application.

As far as the `Echo` templates are considered, you are right. None of the templating libraries including Go, Java, Node.js, etc. are designed to support such operations. Ideally, if you are doing server-rendered web applications, then you must do such calculations within the controller/model section of the code and then send all the data as context to the templating library or code whose job is to just format it into HTML/JSON or XML. Templating solutions should not have such complex data manipulation behavior.

For the title of the question:

> Is it good to use echo or go's templates to show complex data in frontend?

It is definitely a bad idea - a path leading nowhere. You must process the complex data in your MVC controllers or models and let template engine simply format that data. Alternately, if you are doing single page applications or complex interactive UI applications, then expose your data as JSON via REST/GraphQL APIs and let front-end code call those APIs using `fetch` or `XHR` and do the further processing.